# What type is returned from nodes() in a SQL Server XML query

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql

If I have a SQL variable of the XML type, it's possible to use it directly as a column of the SELECT clause (even if the value is an XML fragment without a single root element)

```
DECLARE @Items XML
SET @Items = '<item>one</item><item>two</item>'
SELECT @Items
```

Yet when I shred that XML variable in any way using the `nodes()` function, SQL Server complains that

```
SELECT Items.Item FROM @Items.nodes('/') AS Items (Item)
-- The column 'Item' that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be used directly. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks.
```

It's fine when I follow the hints contained in the error message

```
SELECT Items.Item.query('.') FROM @Items.nodes('/') AS Items (Item)
SELECT Items.Item.query('.') FROM @Items.nodes('//item') AS Items (Item)
```

But I can't even convert the result back to XML without using one of those "XML data type" methods.

```
SELECT CAST(Items.Item AS XML) FROM @Items.nodes('/') AS Items (Item)
-- The column that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be converted to the data type xml. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks.
```

What is the data type of the `Items.Item` column and why can't I use it as XML without involving additional methods ( when it's clearly possible to directly select a column of the XML data type?)

Comment: It's just the way the syntax was designed, probably a restriction because of the way the query plan is built. Just work around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation says it is a **rowset**. Here is an excerpt from it:

> The result of the nodes() method is a rowset that contains logical
> copies of the original XML instances. In these logical copies, the
> context node of every row instance is set to one of the nodes that is
> identified with the query expression. This way, later queries can
> navigate relative to these context nodes.

[nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ``nodes()`` itself returns a rowset (which must subsequently be aliased to use the table and single column) but my question is more about the type of the column "Item" that was part of that rowset.

Comment: @Jono that is also covered by this quote. Each row is a copy of the original XML instance. In these logical copies, the context node of every row instance is set to match each identified node

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a slightly different example.

```
DECLARE @Items XML
SET @Items = '<data><item>one</item><item>two</item></data>'

SELECT Items.Item.query('.') 
FROM @Items.nodes('data/item') AS Items (Item)
```

This returns the results below

| Items.Item.query('.') |
| --- |
| <item>one</item> |
| <item>two</item> |

I have added an additional column below to indicate what the result of `Items.Item` conceptually would be for each row returned.

| Items.Item.query('.') | Items.Item |
| --- | --- |
| <item>one</item> | [image] |
| <item>two</item> | [image] |

This is the **same document** as the input document to the `nodes` method is. Just the context node (indicated by the arrow) is set differently in each row.

You can see this by using the `..` expression to select the parent of the context node

```
SELECT Items.Item.query('..') AS [Items.Item.query('..')]
FROM @Items.nodes('data/item') AS Items (Item)
```

Returns

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|            Items.Item.query('..')             |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| <data><item>one</item><item>two</item></data> |
| <data><item>one</item><item>two</item></data> |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

If it was possible to select `Items.Item` directly I doubt that this would be the expectation of users that it would just return the input document. If you wanted to just return the input document you can just select this directly

```
SELECT Items.Item.query('.') AS [Items.Item.query('.')], @Items
FROM @Items.nodes('data/item') AS Items (Item)
```

Comment: I would have thought that ``@Items`` was the XML of the _unshredded_ document

Comment: I see how it wouldn't make sense to use the results of ``nodes()`` directly, but after it's been aliased with TABLE(COLUMN) and it's actually been split into multiple rows (assuming the argument fed to ``nodes()`` would result in multiple rows, of course) and we've selected the column from that pseudo table, I find it peculiar I cannot treat that column as XML.

Comment: **Both** are the XML of the unshredded document. Both are the same XML. This is demonstrated in the final SELECT query in my answer that returns the whole original document. The only difference is that the context node points to a specific place in that document when returned from the nodes method.  If you actually want the original document just add @Items to the SELECT list. Probably most people would not want that anyway though as it is the same document for every row returned by the nodes method

Comment: @Jono - I've restructured my answer to try and address your confusion

Comment: I don't think I am confused (thanks, Dunning-Kruger effect), but thank you for clarifying. I understand the XML of the @Items variable is exactly the same as the XML in each row returned by ``nodes()``, with the subtle difference that the context is at the root for @Items, but is in other places (depending on the argument passed in) with ``nodes()``. It would satisfy me to know that the language designers wanted to avoid violating the principle of least surprise with the restriction they imposed on the latter. I mean: would you expect the whole XML or just the context if you cast as XML?